# Differences between server update time and site update time

Tags: request

I'm using Python to crawl the web every second.

When the article is posted on the site, you can see the completion time of the writing.

For example, if the writing time is 40:10 seconds, the time shown on the site is 20 seconds later.

There is a time difference between when an administrator publishes to a site and when it actually displays on a site.

I tried request() while deleting the cache, but it's the same.

Is it possible to resolve the problem that appears late on the site?

Or can I check it right away when a new article is updated on the server?